# Google vision response labels not returning in raw JSON format

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-vision, google-vision, json-serialization

I'm trying to get the response to be in the `JSON` format and for some reason Google's sample code throws a bunch of `{}` in the response. Using the code below I can get the response but its not in `JSON` format.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Instantiates a client
        try (ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create()) {

            // The path to the image file to annotate
            String fileName = "src/main/resources/city-park.jpg";

            // Reads the image file into memory
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

            // Builds the image annotation request
            List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
            Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
            Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();
            AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder()
                    .addFeatures(feat)
                    .setImage(img)
                    .build();
            requests.add(request);

            // Performs label detection on the image file
            BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);

            System.out.println(response.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the sample code will print that is close to JSON but formatted wrong. Is there anyway to get it formatted correctly?

```
responses {
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/02l215"
    description: "Reflection"
    score: 0.9883928
    topicality: 0.9883928
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/05h0n"
    description: "Nature"
    score: 0.98085856
    topicality: 0.98085856
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/03d28y3"
    description: "Natural landscape"
    score: 0.9740803
    topicality: 0.9740803
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/0838f"
    description: "Water"
    score: 0.9714835
    topicality: 0.9714835
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/038hg"
    description: "Green"
    score: 0.9620494
    topicality: 0.9620494
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/01bqvp"
    description: "Sky"
    score: 0.96003544
    topicality: 0.96003544
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/015s2f"
    description: "Water resources"
    score: 0.9593428
    topicality: 0.9593428
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/07j7r"
    description: "Tree"
    score: 0.9462387
    topicality: 0.9462387
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/01fnns"
    description: "Vegetation"
    score: 0.9326158
    topicality: 0.9326158
  }
  label_annotations {
    mid: "/m/02yq2x"
    description: "Reflecting pool"
    score: 0.8776601
    topicality: 0.8776601
  }
}
```

Edit: I wanted to make a quick edit to my post because while all the answers here are great and helped I found that this was what made it work the way I wanted.
`String theData = com.google.protobuf.util.JsonFormat.printer().print(response);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BatchAnnotateImagesResponse](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/vision/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/vision/v1/model/BatchAnnotateImagesResponse.html) class extends `com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson` but it does not generate `JSON` by default. You need to set [JsonFactory](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/json/JsonFactory.html). You can choose provider: [JacksonFactory](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/json/jackson2/JacksonFactory.html), [GsonFactory](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/latest/com/google/api/client/json/gson/GsonFactory.html) or other. After that, `toString` method should generate valid `JSON`. Example:

```
response.setFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance());
response.toString();
```

See also:

- [Pluggable streaming library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-http-java-client/json.html)

Comment: Having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to setfactory. Is there a place where I can find examples of how to do so? Sorry I'm still learning java.

Comment: @JamesMartin, take a look on this [codota - GenericJson.setFactory](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson/setFactory). For example, [TestUtils](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/oauth2_http/javatests/com/google/auth/TestUtils.java#L87)